# What are the numbers on arrows in Storm visualization?

Tags: apache-storm

After submitted topology i got with storm visulaization the following picture but didn't get what are the numbers on the arrows ? I searched more to get any clarifaction but couldn't find 
Any help will appreciate

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please correct this answer if incorrect, but when I examined my topology, I saw that the first set of words you see are the stream names. Then comes the number of tuples being transmitted. The percentage shows you what percentage of the capacity (throughput) of the stream is being taken up.

Comment: thanks for replying, Does high percentage of capacity means good or not ?

Comment: There is no good or bad. Nothing wrong in using 100% capacity. Nothing wrong in using 1% capacity.